# How can I add Images to jQuery Mobile Select Menu Items

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to create a jQuery mobile select menu with images for each option. The basic version is described in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-selects.html). I know there are some jQuery plugins which realize this, but I would like to do it with jQuery mobile only.

Has someone already realized this or has an idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I have a mobile web with this case working (but it's not still available).
Try this:

**1. Create CSS styles** for the images, and give this clause:

CSS:

```
.eur {background: url(../images/flags/EuropeanUnion.png) 5px 50% no-repeat; padding: 3px 0 3px 35px; font-size: 16px;}
.usd {background: url(../images/flags/us.png) 5px 50% no-repeat; padding: 3px 0 3px 35px; font-size: 16px;}
.gbp {background: url(../images/flags/gb.png) 5px 50% no-repeat; padding: 3px 0 3px 35px; font-size: 16px;}
```

HTML:

```
<option value="eur" class="eur" selected="selected">Euro</option>
<option value="usd" class="usd">US Dollar</option>
<option value="gbp" class="gbp">GB Pound</option>
```

And check the CSS new clauses are working in each option.

**2. Understand the DOM:**

In your html you have something like this:

```
<select data-mini="true" class="select-with-images">
  <option value="eur" class="eur" selected="selected">Euro</option>
  <option value="usd" class="usd">US Dollar</option>
  <option value="gbp" class="gbp">GB Pound</option>
</select>
```

But jQuery Mobile generates this:

```
<div class="ui-select">
  <div data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">Euro</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
    </span>
    <select class="select-with-images" data-mini="true">
      <option selected="selected" class="eur" value="eur">Euro</option>
      <option class="usd" value="usd">US Dollar</option>
      <option class="gbp" value="gbp">GB Pound</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**3. The jQuery**

So you have to get the image class of the selected option and give it to `span.ui-btn-tex` each time you change the select, and first of all when jQuery Mobile is rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //select-with-images
  $('.select-with-images').on('change', function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $(this).parents('.ui-select').find('.ui-btn-text').attr('class', 'ui-btn-text '+selection);
  });
  $(document).on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.select-with-images').each(function() {
      var selection = $(this).find(':selected').val();
      $(this).parents('.ui-select').find('.ui-btn-text').attr('class', 'ui-btn-text '+selection);
    });
  });
});
```

That works for me.

Comment: I have tried this but not work for me. could u please give 
http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: Interesting approach. One reason this is not working is because dom ready was missing it's closing }); (fixed it) Another reason (in IE) is because IE does not support console.log() unless the developer tools (F12) is open. Removing that line in the JS will help. There was also a bug in the code (fixed). I also prefer using .addClass(selection); instead of .attr('class', 'ui-btn-text '+selection) in the mouseover listener. I can't replicate your specific background images, but here's a working fiddle for you (or those who come along later, like I have) http://jsfiddle.net/ARZQw/11/

Comment: Here is another example for anyone using the data-native-menu="false" option. http://jsfiddle.net/Strixy/gKbDw/

Answer (score 1):

Use an inspector (eg. firebug) to get the idea of how the elements are created and after they're ready add the images to the spans in there. That's the only way to make it work with jquery mobile without modifying JQM itself.

Also - in the fresh release ofjQuery Mobile alpha4 the select is rendered with default browser component by default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I just changed it from a select menu to a dialog. This was much easier.